# Using Zonal Histogram for each pixel in a raster by creating a buffer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, zonal-statistics, count

I was looking to use the Zonal Histogram for each pixel in a raster by creating a buffer (let's say of 500 meters) for a LULC map of 100 meter resolution. I'm using ArcGIS 10.6., Model builder.

One approach I tried was to convert raster to point, then  created buffer map using the point shapefile. Then I use the iterate feature selection on buffer map and gave it as input to Zonal Histogram along with original LULC map. The problem starts here, I don't get either list of tables. I tried to merge them in model itself but still it doesn't work.
[image: Iterator Model with Pivot Table]
[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: I Think your model should work. Could you add a screenshot of it? What do you mean by  "I tried to merge them in model itself but still it doesn't work."? I doubt that will work if you are doing this inside the iterating model

Comment: Do you really need the whole histogram or some of characteristics? Many of them can be extracted using fast raster calculations.

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the Model builder. The merge was not working due to duplicate inputs. So I've to pivot all the outputs.   @BERA , the merge is outside the model. Now the Pivot is not working. There is a problem with the 'Value field'. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I actually need the count of the pixels belonging to the different classes within the buffer.   @FelixIP , by fast raster calculations do you mean the Sum, Average and other in focal statistics option?

Comment: I Think you need to replace `%name%` with `%Value%`. Or rename the turquoise ellipse to `name`

Comment: Yes, focal statistics on N binary rasters, where N is number of classes. It will work much faster on a decent size raster. Still slow, but doable.

Comment: You can combine rasters or sample them after, to produce a table.

Comment: I tried replacing %name% with %Value% but still it's not able to pivot the table. I've attached the screenshot. @BERA The value field 'is OBJEC_15' in first iteration and so I basically need to input the value field such that it has 'OBJEC_' as common name and anything in front of it with number. Still don't know how to do this in arcpy.